# Bash - for loop with range of variables

Tags: bash

Trying to print range of ip addresses to a file. Instead of looping through the range it just prints one line containing the variable values.

http://tpcg.io/0lCSJr

```
cidr="192.168.0.1/24"

# range is bounded by network (-n) & broadcast (-b) addresses.
lo=$(ipcalc -n $cidr |cut -f2 -d=)
hi=$(ipcalc -b $cidr |cut -f2 -d=)

read a b c d <<< $(echo $lo |tr . ' ')
# echo $a.$b.$c.$d
read e f g h <<< $(echo $hi |tr . ' ')
# echo $e.$f.$g.$h


for ip in {$a..$e}.{$b..$f}.{$c..$g}.{$d..$h};
do
    echo $ip > results.txt
done;
```

Current output is...

```
{192..192}.{168..168}.{0..0}.{0..255}
```

If given `192.168.0.1/24` looking for how to get the output to print each host in that network on each line in a file...

```
192.168.0.0
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
...
192.168.0.255
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: `{$a..$e}.{$b..$f}.{$c..$g}.{$d..$h}` will not work because _brace expansion_ does not accept variables as arguments.

Comment: brace expansion and variables don't work without `eval`

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #33](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D)

Comment: BTW, this is overwriting `results.txt` from the beginning over and over. Do you want to move the `> results.txt` after the `done`, so all the invocations write to a single file? (Still need to fix the file, ofc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I meant append or write all to the same file.

Comment: @Karakfa `eval "echo {$a..$e}.{$b..$f}.{$c..$g}.{$d..$h}" >> ip_range.txt` I tried this and it does write all the IP addresses to the file.

Comment: right, but beware of `eval` risks if the content is not under your control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usage of `seq` and `xargs` looks cool and funny:

```
seq 192 192 |
xargs -i seq -f "{}.%.0f" 168 168 |
xargs -i seq -f "{}.%.0f" 0 0 |
xargs -i seq -f "{}.%.0f" 0 255
```

So in your script that would be:

```
seq $a $e |
xargs -i seq -f "{}.%.0f" $b $f |
xargs -i seq -f "{}.%.0f" $c $g |
xargs -i seq -f "{}.%.0f" $d $h |
while read ip; do
   ...
done
```

or you could `for ip in $(seq $a $e | .... ); do`, but that would be less cool.

What's good, it's easy to make it a function.

Answer (score 0):

This works...it writes all the ip addresses to a file using `eval` instead of the loop and then I split them by space and replace the space with newline into another file.

```
cidr=$1

# range is bounded by network (-n) & broadcast (-b) addresses.
lo=$(ipcalc -n $cidr |cut -f2 -d=)
hi=$(ipcalc -b $cidr |cut -f2 -d=)

read a b c d <<< $(echo $lo |tr . ' ')
echo $a.$b.$c.$d
read e f g h <<< $(echo $hi |tr . ' ')
echo $e.$f.$g.$h

eval "echo {$a..$e}.{$b..$f}.{$c..$g}.{$d..$h}" > ip_range.txt

tr ' ' '\n' < ip_range.txt > results.txt
```

Also you could do this instead and edit the spacing in one go...

```
cidr=$1

# range is bounded by network (-n) & broadcast (-b) addresses.
lo=$(ipcalc -n $cidr |cut -f2 -d=)
hi=$(ipcalc -b $cidr |cut -f2 -d=)

read a b c d <<< $(echo $lo |tr . ' ')
echo $a.$b.$c.$d
read e f g h <<< $(echo $hi |tr . ' ')
echo $e.$f.$g.$h

eval "printf '%s\n' {$a..$e}.{$b..$f}.{$c..$g}.{$d..$h}" > ip_range.txt
```

Comment: `tr ' ' '\n'` ? Why not print newline the first time? `eval "printf '%s\n' {$a.. ...."`